# Equal panel height in different facet_grid plots, ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to have two facet_grid plots side by side, one with 3 rows and another with 2 using `ggplot2` in R. By default `grid.arrange` tries to maintain the equal height of two `facet_grids` however, I want to have equal panel height for both plots.Particularly I want to adjust the panel height of plot with least number of rows to be equal to the panel height of the plot with maximum number of rows. I don't think it should be quite complicated. Am I missing some common idea here? Since I am newbie to R any help would be kindly appreciated Thank you!

A reproducible example is here:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
mtcars
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x =mpg,y = disp,fill=cyl))+
geom_point()+
facet_grid(rows=vars(gear),cols=vars(cyl),scales = "free")

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x =mpg,y = disp,fill=cyl))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(rows=vars(am),cols=vars(cyl),scales = "free")

grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
```

which produces

[image: a 3x3 facet plot same size as a 2x3 facet plot]

I want to have p2 have panel height as of p1 and use the bottom empty space from p2 (right) for the legend the remaining space empty. And yes I have to maintain scale to be free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not very elegant, but you can perhaps  draw an empty rectangle, combine it vertically with your `p2` and then combine with `p1`:

```
library(grid)
empty_panel <- grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white"))

p2t <- grid.arrange(p2,empty_panel,ncol=1, heights=c(0.7,0.3))
grid.arrange(p1,p2t,ncol=2)
```

the output looks like [image]

If you want the extra space to be used to place, for example, your legend, an option could be to play with `legend.position` and `plot.margin`:

```
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x =mpg,y = disp,fill=cyl))+
   geom_point()+
   facet_grid(rows=vars(am),cols=vars(cyl),scales = "free")+
   
   theme(plot.margin= unit(c(0, 0, 4, 0), "cm")     ,legend.position = c(0.5, -0.3))
 
 grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
```

some manual adjustment is required.

the plot will loook like:
[image]

Comment: @ efz Many thanks for the answer. However it wasn't exactly the one I was looking for. Actually I want to keep information like legend in that empty space so that the complete plot would have better look. With this idea I need to do trials to define the size of empty panel.  Do you have any better idea for this?

Comment: @SuwasGhimire You should edit the question with that information, it's important. Do you want to/can you treat the empty space as a third plot? The only thing I'm seeing that could improve this answer is to lower the right plot legend to align it with the left one.

Comment: @Rui Barradas you got me right. That's what I exactly want. I want to have the legend from 2nd plot (right one) here in this case to the empty space. (question edited accordingly)

Comment: @SuwasGhimire see if my edited answer gets closer to what you're after

Comment: @ Many thanks efz. Its closer to what I look for. I have marked it as answer.